# Precise mode in Boehm Garbage Collector

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, boehm-gc

I've read on the webpage of Mono that they are using the Boehm GC in precise mode. I too use the Boehm GC with C++, however, I have found nothing in its documentation or headers that would indicate a precise mode, much less how to turn it on.

Any information whether it actually has a precise mode by default and how to turn it on, or it was just some kind of modification by Mono developers?

Comment: I believe the precise mode needs support from the compiler to indicate exactly where pointers are stored. Typecasting in C and C++ makes this next to impossible.

Comment: So I've heard. However I thought it might contain some compiler/platform specific solution to make it possible in a transparent manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file doc/gcinterface.html from the garbage collector ([archive here](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/gc_source/gc.tar.gz)) states:

> void * GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC(size_t nbytes)
>       Allocates nbytes of storage. Requires (amortized) time
>   proportional to nbytes. The resulting object will be automatically
>   deallocated when unreferenced. The client promises that the resulting
>   object will never contain any pointers. The memory is not cleared.
>   This is the preferred way to allocate strings, floating point arrays,
>   bitmaps, etc. More precise information about pointer locations can be
>   communicated to the collector using the interface in gc_typed.h in the
>   distribution.

It looks like there is a "precise" interface that can be used.

Comment: I believe it is far fetched to call such a simple construct "precise". It does not solve the case where pointers and other stuff is mixed.

Comment: Okay, I am going to accept this as the answer. There seems to be no satisfactory precise mode in Boehm, but GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC or its C++ equivalent, operator new [] (size, PointerFreeGC) alleviate the problem somewhat. I now use the latter for Array<int32>, Array<float>, etc.

Comment: @Frigo There is a precise mode (as much as Mono is precise) in Boehm that you could use in C++. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Precise mode in Boehm GC under Mono isn't just `GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC`. It's only true for arrays of fundamental types.

For managed types, `GC_gcj_malloc` is used. Mono's compiler generates an object descriptor for every managed type and it then simply calls `GC_gcj_malloc` with an argument of size, and a pointer to the managed type's descriptor. Boehm GC then refers to the descriptor during mark phase to trace the managed pointers.

You will end up with just the root pointers sitting on the stack as raw pointers (`GC_gcj_malloc` returns a void* and there's no way to tell the GC where the pointers are on the stack via some sort of a stack descriptor prior to GC collect). This is the reason Mono (prior to SGen) says they scan the stack in conservative mode.

If you want to implement this under C++, you won't be able to simply rely on the C++ compiler to generate the object descriptor for you. What I envisioned a long time ago was to write an intermediate compiler that parses all your C++ header files for class definitions that have been marked as managed class (e.g. `_ref class MyManagedObject` where `_ref` is simply a `#define` to nothing) and generate a header file containing those object descriptors. You would then use the `GC_make_descriptor` and `GC_malloc_explicitly_typed` functions to allocate your objects in precise mode rather than `GC_gcj_malloc` as you would not have control over how your C++ compiler allocates its vtable.

*EDIT: See [Managed C++ for GCC (open source GPL v3)](http://managedcpp.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the precise mode needs support from the compiler to indicate exactly where pointers are stored. Typecasting in C and C++ makes this next to impossible.

A managed language, with built in reflection, would make this a lot easier.